# Does Shoes have a list view control?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I was taking a look at Shoes which seems like a very nice tool for quick GUI applications.  The common elements/controls, however, don't seem to include the equivalent of a list/report view (*e.g.*, ListView in Windows, NSTableView in OS X).

Did I just miss this, or does it not (yet) exist?

Comment: Thanks - I didn't want to do that initially as I didn't want to create noise for Ruby-only people.

Comment: Do you need ListView or a Virtual ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean output a large quantity of textual data such as a report or table then there's a nice simple app in the shoebox called the [Simple Table Class](http://the-shoebox.org/apps/101) which works very nicely. Before I found it i was ready to give shoes up - but this class solved my problem in minutes.

Looking for it i stumbled across [laces](http://github.com/eveel/laces) which includes a class called The Tablie. I haven't tried it but I am suddenly intrigued....

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be. Shoes [Classes](http://help.shoooes.net/Classes.html) doesn't seem to mention anything similar.

I guess it shouldn't be too difficult to manually create something similar. The [good-vjot.rb](http://github.com/why/shoes/blob/f107ec71ca58ddeaea09d85f1f11197a13f15561/samples/good-vjot.rb) sample script is probably the closest I can think of, although it's hardly identical..

[Martin DeMello's Gooey Challenge
(Using Shoes widgets to build custom Shoes controls)](http://hackety.org/2008/06/12/martinDemellosGooeyChallenge.html) may be of some help

Answer (score 0):

```
Shoes.app do
  stack do
    @l = list_box :items => ["YES", "NO"] do
      alert @l.text
    end
  end
end
```