# Equivalent to HTML Listbox in Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, listbox, shoes

I've seen that the listbox control provided by Shoes is a dropdown/combobox.  (documentation can be found at http://shoesrb.com/manual/ListBox.html).  Instead I need a control similar to this:

[image]

I could probably extend the Editbox to achieve similar functionality, but this is my first time using the language, and this seems like an extremely basic UI element to have been omitted.  Is this sort of control available?  Google searches have been hellish because of the identical name returning results for a control that is useless for my purposes.

The question [Does Shoes have a list view control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450535/does-shoes-have-a-list-view-control) looks like it had useful information at one time, but the links are all broken now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an element in shoes that would do that out of the box.

I know this is something different from what you're looking for, but would it be acceptable to show all options in a stack with formatted radio buttons? See my example with green shoes.

```
require 'green_shoes'

Shoes.app do
 stack width: 400 do
  flow do
   background gray
   para "Select an option:"
 end
  flow do
   background lavender
   @a = radio :options
   para "Option 1", width: 300
 end
  flow do
   background lightcyan
   @b = radio :options
   para "Option 2", width: 300
   @b.focus  
 end
  flow do
   background lavender
   @c = radio :options
   para "Option 3", width: 300
  end
 end
end
```

regards,

seba

Comment: Unfortuanetly no.  I'll probably revert to java for this unless there's a ruby GUI package that will work.  I'm dealing with a set of options that can be searched and filtered.  Currently its only 500 or so, but that number will increase over time.